# Pass a string in a struct to a function and return it

Tags: c, string, struct, return-type

I want to return the name of the smallest city population-wise, if it is the second city. (Please don't mind the if statement, I know it's bland), the missing return is what bothers me.

I assume I should declare a pointer inside the function `rSmallestCity`, like `*rtrn` but I guess the source variable is destroyed before it is used?

```
typedef struct Coordinate{
    int x,y;
}Coordinate;

typedef struct city{
    char name[20];
    int population;
    Coordinate coordinates;
}city;

char *rSmallestCity(city **cl, int n)
{
     char *rtrn = NULL;
     if(cl[n-2]->population>cl[n-1]->population)
     {
         rtrn = &cl[n-1]->name;
     }
     return rtrn;
}

int main()
{
    city c1 ={.name="Mumbai", .population=310, .coordinates.x=3, .coordinates.y=4};
    city c2 ={.name="Delhi", .population=300, .coordinates.x=3, .coordinates.y=2};
    city *clist[2];
    clist[0]=&c1;
    clist[1]=&c2;
    printf("\n%s is smallest\n",rSmallestCity(clist,2));
}
```

> warning: assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Comment: You should enable warnings in your compiler. The missing `return` is not the only problem. A `char` is not a suitable type to return a pointer to a string.

Comment: You already have a variable `char *rtrn`. What stops you from using it in else part?

Comment: Among other problems: consider what happens if the condifion `cl[n-2]->population>cl[n-1]->population` is false.

Comment: warning: returning 'char *' from a function with return type 'char' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

Comment: Gerhardh, the goal is print the return value.

Comment: Change your function to return `char*` not simple `char`. (the warning warns you about this)

Comment: As the other guys already wrote, You have to return something in any case, if it is a non-void function. So simply initialize rtrn to NULL and return it anyway, But before doing it, change the return type of rSmallestCity. It has to be `char *`, not `char`.

Comment: Great thanks guys, this now works but still one warning. warning: assignment to 'char *' from incompatible pointer type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Comment: Your `rSmallestCity` really needs to use a loop to find the smallest.

Comment: And check rSmallestCity 's return value against NULL before passing it to printf. In some environment the latter is protected against null pointers and will print "(null)", but it is safer and more portable perform the check yourself.

Comment: @futureExpert what is the row raising the warning?

Comment: remove & in the line `&cl[n-1]->name;`

Comment: Your function rSmallestCity only needs to receive a pointer to city, not a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Stef1611 thanks, was that.

Comment: Roberto Caboni, was the &cl[n-1]->name;

Comment: Please do not change your code after comments or answers have been given. This makes all those comments useless. If you have a new version, you can add it but removing initial content should be avoided.

Comment: @futureExpert. Read my answer. I think it could avoid you some strange behaviour of your future programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume I should declare a pointer inside the function rSmallestCity, like *rtrn but I guess the source variable is destroyed before it is used?*

A good question. And your assumption is correct.  Creating a variable inside a function it's existence ends upon leaving the function.  But in this case, because the struct member `name` is already a `char *` you do not need to create another variable.  Just return `c1.name`. (see code example below.)

A few other suggestions:

In the struct declaration:

```
typedef struct Coordinate{
    int x,y;
}Coordinate;
```

You've used the same symbol (`Coordinate`) for the struct name, and for it's typedef.  This is not a good practice.  If you need both a struct name *and* a typedef, pick different symbols.  BTW, in this this example, only one or the other is needed.  Say you pick the typedef, then the struct is completely defined by:

```
typedef struct {
    int x,y;
}Coordinate;
```

That suggestion applies to both `struct` declarations in your example code.

The signatures for the `main` function do not include `int main(){...}`  rather
`int main(void){..., return 0;}` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){..., return 0;}`

The following code example illustrates some of the other suggestions for improvements in comments under your post,

```
typedef struct {
    int x,y;
}Coordinate;

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int population;
    Coordinate coordinates;
}city;

//return char * rather than char to allow for full null terminated char array (string)
char * rSmallestCity(city c1[],int cityCount)//generisize function prototype to 
{                                            //to easily accommodate bigger arrays if needed
    long long size, sizeKeep = 8e9; //index and population. initialize larger than possible population
    int indexKeep = 0;
    //note you do not need to define a char *, the struct already contains one

    for(int i=0; i<cityCount; i++)//use a loop rather than a single comparison, keep the smalles
    {
        size = c1[i].population; 
        sizeKeep = (size < sizeKeep) ? indexKeep = i, size  : sizeKeep;
    }

    printf("\n%s\n",c1[indexKeep].name);
    return c1[indexKeep].name;
};

int main(void)//use minimum signature for main, and call return before leaving.
{
        //combining your original declarations and assignments for struct
        //into a single declaration/definition.
        city c1[] = {{.name="Mumbai", .population=310, .coordinates.x=3, .coordinates.y=4},
                    {.name="Delhi",  .population=300, .coordinates.x=3, .coordinates.y=2}};
        int cityCount = sizeof(c1)/sizeof(c1[0]);

        printf("\n%s is smallest",rSmallestCity(c1, cityCount));

        return 0;
};
```

Comment: Regarding typedef, noted to self and changed. int cityCount = sizeof(c1)/sizeof(c1[0]); that is clever! I will dig into the other comments later on! Great remarks.

Comment: @futureExpert - Thank you.  If you have questions about any of it, just drop a comment here and I will try to answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I originally left in comment under OP (remove `&` in the line `&cl[n-1]->name;`) needs some explanations to avoid problems later.

(It is an educational answer not a full answer on pointers, array decay, ... And many examples can be found on stackoverflow. I tried to simplify)

Try this simple code.

```
int main()
{
    char myString1[25]="Toulouse" ; // French City
    printf("%p\n",myString1);
    printf("%p\n",&myString1);
}
```

The output is the same, but an array name and the address of an array name are not the same. The array name is evaluated to the address of its first element. So it works in your case but a warning is issued during compilation and it is very important. Firstly, do not remove compilation warnings.

Now, try this code :

```
int main()
{
    char myString1[25]="Toulouse" ; // French City
    printf("%p\n",myString1+1);
    printf("%p\n",&myString1+1);
}
```

The outputs are different. Because `myString1` is evaluated to `char*` and `&myString1` to `char [25]`. So `+1`, in the first, case adds one (`sizeof char`) to the pointer and in the other case, it adds 25.

Comment: It should be clear that you are the first to suggest this in the comments, so I have upclicked your answer here, and edited your post with a few minor changes to make the fact you are the original to post this observation.  (If you do not agree with my edit, you can always roll it back to your original.)

Comment: @ryyker. Thanks to edit and to correct my english. Concerning that I am the first ... OK. But it was easy to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the "&" in the line:
`rtrn = &cl[n-1]->name;`

To extremely simplify, you assigned an "address of `char[]`" to a `char*`, but array syntax makes it work regardless.

Comment: I am sorry. But I think some explanations are needed. It is not possible "To extremely simplify" as you wrote. I am afraid that it could cause confusions. When I posted this answer in the comment I was thinking to an educational answer. Do not hesitate to comment it.